# i installed android studio and vs code in a new laptop when i try to run the emulator from the android studio in vs code i get the error

Tags: flutter, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:parseDebugLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-33\android.jar.
> > C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-33\android.jar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 58s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

i tried uninstalling the emulator and reinstalling it